# Updating [placeholder] Reactive Form Control Programmatically

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following `formControl` as part of my Reactive Form:

```
<input class="input" formControlName="email" [placeholder]="">
```

I was wondering if there were a way to set the placeholder programmatically?

Something like: `this.formGroup.get('email').placeholder = 'Some value';`

Answer (score 11):

The `placeholder` is a property of the HTML element itself, not the `formGroup`. You can directly bind it like you're doing with a component property (`[placeholder]="someValue"`) and Angular's change detection will update it automatically..

You can also grab the element itself via `@ViewChild` and update it as a property of the element (i.e. vanilla JS):

```
<input #myInput />

// ...

@ViewChild('myInput') myInput: ElementRef;

// ...

myInput.nativeElement.placeholder = 'New Thing';
```

If you have a somewhat normalized behavior for these placeholders, you can even extrapolate this into a `Directive` that accomplishes this behavior in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 3):

yo can create a function in your component like

```
getPlaceholder(key: string): string
```

this function will generate the placeholder that you want based on the name that you pass

later in your template you can call this function

```
<input class="input" formControlName="email" [placeholder]="getPlaceholder('email')">
```

Other solution can be extend the FormControl class.

```
export class MyCustomFormControl extends FormControl {
  _placeholder: string 
  constructor(...config) {
    super(config)
  }

  set placeholder(key:string){
    this._placeholder = key
  } 
  get placeholder() {
   return this._placeholder
  }
}
```

and push your custom formControl to the FormGroup . 
with this approach you going to be able to call `from.controls['email'].placeholder`

Comment: I've read that it is usually more efficient to bind to a component property instead of calling a function. Will this function, because of Angular's Change Detection continually be executed?

Comment: that's true, angular will call this function multiples time (every time that you move the mouse)

Comment: That's true. Angular will always be running change detection, but it works by comparing values. When it compares the value of a function, it needs to run that function for the return value. A value that's just a property is more efficient to check.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator in [placeholder]. e.g `[placeholder]="1==1?'true': 'false'"`