# Can we set FomControl's placehoder when adding control in FormArray?

Tags: angular, formarray, formgroups

Wondering if I can add placeholder text for the `FormControl` (in component), here is my code:

```
(this.paramsForm.get(
        'parameters'
      ) as FormArray).push(new FormControl('', [Validators.required]));
```

rendering in html

```
<div  *ngFor="let formControl of paramsForm.get('parameters').controls">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="block push-bottom">
    <input
      matInput
      type="text"
      [formControl]="formControl" //TODO
      placeholder="formControl" //TODO
    />
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

---

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117510/updating-placeholder-reactive-form-control-programatically) is helpful, but in my case, having an object array (`{controlName:'name', value:'', placeholder: 'Enter name'}, {controlName:'email', value:'', placeholder: 'Enter email'}`) to dynamically create controls and setting placeholder text for each.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating \[placeholder\] Reactive Form Control Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117510/updating-placeholder-reactive-form-control-programatically)

Comment: No. a fromGroup is independent of exist a input or not. But you can store in a variable (or in an array of variables) your placeholder, add to the loop ;let i=index and use [placeholder]="myplaceHolder[i]", where myplaceHolder is an array with the place holder

Comment: @Eliseo, based on our suggestion, found a solution (posted as answer too). Thanks!

Comment: @Eliseo an object mapping would be better; Using like: `<input [placeholder]='myPlaceholder["control"]' />`

Answer (score 0):

After @Eliseo comment, keeping placeholders text in an array, below is the outcome:

**my JSON object:**

`exportParameters`:   [groupTitle:'Export Group', parameters:[{key:'username', value:'', displayName:'Enter user name'}, key:'password', value:'', displayName:'Enter password'} ]]

**in component.ts, created a group**

```
placeholders: string[] = [];

this.paramsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
exportParameters: this.fb.group({
      parameters: this.fb.array([])
    })
})


this.exportParameters.parameters.forEach( (param,index) => {
(this.paramsForm.get('exportParameters.parameters') as FormArray).push (new FormControl('',[Validatrors.required]));
this.placeholders[index] = param.displayName;
})
```

**in component's html:**

```
<div *ngFor="let formControl of paramsForm.get('exportParameters.parameters').controls; let i = index;">

<mat-form-field>
<input type="text" placeholder = "{{ placeholders[i] }}" />
</mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Hope this helps someone !